# $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] change after migrating to SSL

Tags: php

We recently migrated to SSL, and the site works great with the exception of one function. The function uses curl in the code below to execute an api located on the same server. The url variable for this function is: news.hubsdev.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_api&task=acymailing.listcreate

it returned a 301 error, until we added

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

However, now it returns a an error due to the fact that the global variable $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] has changed somehow.  It returns an error when we test to make sure it is "POST" using the following:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
```

Could our switch to SSL change this variable?  How can we fix this?

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: You shouldn't rely on $_SERVER because could be spoofed.

Comment: @elMiedo It seems your comment got spoofed, it doesn't make sense. `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {}` is the safest code there is to determine a post from a get request.

Comment: @Xorifelse I think it makes sense since $_SERVER is not entirely server controlled. What I mean is that we should manage $_SERVER as other user input. In this way, using $_SERVER increase the attack surface. I don't use any input unless it is very necessary.

Comment: Some values yes, browser header, ip and that's about it. Even `REQUEST_METHOD` yes. However changing this as user with the code above would negate the attack, breaking the page. Not giving the results the hacker would have wanted.

Comment: Ok `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {}` I agree is safe. But if you work within a group for example, it is better put the danger clear and avoid it when possible. Somebody could trust in it and mess up, also it is replaceable.

Answer (score 1):

Following a 301 redirect can cause a POST request to be followed up with a GET request.

Change the URL you are requesting to the URL you actually want (i.e. not the old one that now returns a redirect instruction).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  However, we were sending the correct url, beginning with https, and somehow it still gave us a 301 error.

Comment: You will need to examine the specifics of the request being made and the server side code generating the response to determine why it is issuing a 301.

Comment: 301 is a Permanent Redirect HTTP Code, not an error, it shouldn't redirect when using https if you configured everything correctly.